# How to have fixed header after keyboard is shown on iOS?

Tags: ios, reactjs, header, keyboard

The fixed header is scrolling after keyboard is open on iOS device. Is there any possibility to have fixed header after keyboard is open? I do not want to have header scrolling with the content.

Here is explained similar problem:
https://medium.com/@im_rahul/safari-and-position-fixed-978122be5f29

I am facing the problem in the React project using Cordova.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

**use keyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native'** 
[docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

```
   import {
      KeyboardAvoidingView
    } from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>


          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              returnKeyType="next"
              placeholder="Mobile No."
              placeholderTextColor="powderblue"
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
              style={styles.input}
               onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({mobileno:value})}
               value={this.state.mobileno}
            />

            <TextInput
              returnKeyType="go"
              placeholder="Password"
              placeholderTextColor="powderblue"
              style={styles.input}
              secureTextEntry
              ref={input => (this.passwordInput = input)}
               onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({pssd:value})}
               value={this.state.pssd}
            />
          </View>



      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: I am not using react-native so is there any possible solution how to solve this issue using just React and Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding status bar the KeyboardAvoiding will push everything including the header to top, it’s a bug of KeyboardAvoidingView in react native.

To make your header fixed while keyboard is shown, make your statusbar hidden=false

Comment: The question was about React.js and not react-native.