# Should I use media query and transform: translateY(-%) to above the mobile keyboard?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm stuck for almost a day now, I need help.  I don't understand how chat web apps get around this... There are many posts in forums for this issue: I need my footer (or my header) on this page component to move based on height being less than or equal to a phone height, so it is always ready for the mobile keyboard.  For this component (as opposed to a chat window component), I'd rather have (1)the header on screen + (2)the textbox not behind the keyboard than (x3)having the textbox at the bottom of the screen when keyboard is closed (I actually want to keep the keyboard open if autofocus would trigger on mobile) [image: input textbox hidden] [input textbox hidden](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19RZyrjJQhe6D2l8G1q1K337gYVOeUkNV/view?usp=sharing) & [image: header hidden] [header hidden](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zuosMpqrdN4doBarGosKpsBXExlLcXLY/view?usp=sharing)

Here are some stackoverflow threads that describe this problem:
Short/Sweet [7/20/17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204162/position-element-above-mobile-keyboard)
Similar case [3/22/19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258034/how-to-have-fixed-header-after-keyboard-is-shown-on-ios)
These seem to have the answer but [are in jquery](https://medium.com/@im_rahul/safari-and-position-fixed-978122be5f29) which I don't yet understand or [use input.focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970389/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-virtual-keyboard) which I don't know where to put it in reactjs

css

```
.New_Plan_Header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
  top:0%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2fbaff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.644);
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  src: url(./UIConainers/Icons/Fonts/Muli-ExtraLight.ttf);
}
.plan-form {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0%;
  color: #444;
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-left: 56px;
  src: url(./UIConainers/Icons/Fonts/Muli-ExtraLight.ttf);
}
```

js

```
<div className="New_Plan_Header">Plan</div>
<input
  type="search"
  className="plan-form"
  name="title"
  value={note.title}
  onChange={e => this.updateValue(e)}
  placeholder="Title"
  autoFocus={true}
  autoComplete="off"
  //onfocusin="transform: translateY(-600%), bottom:60%"
  />
```

Thanks for reading and your help in advance

> Go to src/UIConainers/Plans/planpages/plannew.js & plannew.css

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading your question title I would say try it out with media querys and look if the result is what you want to achieve. If not come back again :O If you want to try out the **input.focus** thing look up this post [how react programmatically focus input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145549/how-react-programmatically-focus-input/43145841) maybe this is what you need to understand what you have to do

Comment: ok thanks I'll read that but could you save me some time and tell me what script I should use to move footer input up when keyboard enters?

Comment: öhm well look at the post comment with the green upvote that is the one you probably want to implement and change to your needs.

Comment: I added (1) `onClick={this.focus}
            ref={this.textInput}` to input, (2) `this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);` to constructor & (3) `focus() {
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }` outside render within class! sort of makes sense to me but doesn't ..."work"

Comment: I'm [experimenting with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut) `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) {
  .plan-form {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:60%;
  }
}`

Comment: and now `<input onfocus={
              window.scrollTo(0, 0)} />` but it's not working. getting closer...

Comment: `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 9/13) { .plan-form { position: fixed; bottom:0%; }` . I just switched the media query position with the initial position, so the mid-height render appears on portrait. Still can't `onfocus={window.scrollTo(0,0)}`. I hope this will work as well when there is scrollable content in the chat window component (this component is just a small form) –